# Firebase vs iCloud for synchronization

Tags: ios, firebase, synchronization, cloud, icloud

I want to create a simple notes app for iOS. My app will sync the users data across their devices.

My question is if i should go with Firebase or iCloud ?

The problem i am thinking is for images. If users are uploading images to Firebase , my memory limit is going be exceeded quickly, but with iCloud each user has his own memory limit. Is that true ?

Thanks

Comment: What's your memory limit? Firebase scales upto petabytes, more than enough for most applications.

Comment: I want to use a free pricing model. When i go to https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ i see memory limits.